# Route Not Defined at the Second Time Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when trying to set routes after the first one.

this is my routes :

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => 'atribut',
  'as' => 'atribut.'
], function () {

 Route::group(['prefix' => 'tabHome', 'as' => 'tabHome.'], function () {
    Route::get('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'showTab'])->name('showTab');

    Route::post('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataFirst'])->name('addDataFirst');
    Route::get('deleteDataFirst/{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteDataFirst'])->name('deleteDataFirst');

    Route::post('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataSecond'])->name('addDataSecond');
    Route::get('deleteDataSecond/{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteDataSecond'])->name('deleteDataSecond');
  });

});
```

i already set method in controller for both add and delete for both data first and data second

in first view i have a form action :

```
{{route('frontend.atribut.tabHome.addDataFirst')}}
```

it is the same for second view :

```
{{route('frontend.atribut.tabHome.addDataSecond')}}
```

but i get this error :

```
Route [frontend.atribut.tabHome.addDataFirst] not defined.
```

What makes me confused is, when i remove all code related to data second (in both controller and routes) the project can run fine and execute the code for data first.

Basically i have 2 view and each one have form, but the first view can run fine. After i add the same code for second view, i get the error.

Comment: Route URL can not be the same. you have to give a different URL keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both routes use the same URL `Route::post('', ...)`. The second one overwrites the first one. Make your URLs unique like you did with your `deleteDataSecond` routes:

```
Route::post('addDataFirst', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataFirst'])->name('addDataFirst');
```

and

```
Route::post('addDataSecond', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataSecond'])->name('addDataSecond');
```